# Oracle BI: how can i retrieve another result list from current result list

Tags: oracle12c, plsqldeveloper, oracle-bi

I am using Oracle Business Intellgience (12c) and let's say I have a report resulted from an execution of the following query

```
select code_filial, max(paid) as maximum_pay
from leads_history
group by code_filial
```

It will return a table with highest budget value related to the each filial.  Now  what i want is the following: when i click to max(paid) result in a table, another table should appear with the information about max(paid) account. I tried master-detail relationship, but couldn't succeed. 
Can anyoune help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's out-of-the-box functionality. As soon as you make a navigation action link to another analysis where your code_filial is set to "is prompted" the context will be passed and the analysis filtered.